# Eclipse keeps complaining about abstract class - JDK 9 issue?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-oxygen

My eclipse (STS 3.9.2 oxygen, On Ubuntu 16.04, JDK 9.0.4) keeps giving following error. The code used to compile/work fine earlier and only change made was JDK version from 1.8 to 9 and maven compiler plugin was changed accordingly.

Class in question is trying to implement interface org.openqa.selenium.WebElement and get no problems with any other methods.

- Command line compilation with Maven/Java 9 compiles fine
- If I comment the method and ask eclipse to implement missing methods, it generates exact same signature and then complains that method not implemented/override.
- I have tried removing all .project files, and with a new workspace with same results.

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>
> The method sendKeys(CharSequence...) of type JavaScriptDriver.JSWebElement must override or implement a supertype method  JavaScriptDriver.java   /selenium-shared/src/main/java/com/finovera/downloader/driver   line 287    Java Problem
>
> The type JavaScriptDriver.JSWebElement must implement the inherited abstract method WebElement.sendKeys(CharSequence...)  JavaScriptDriver.java   /selenium-shared/src/main/java/com/finovera/downloader/driver   line 98 Java Problem

One more update. This looks like a bug in eclipse compiler as it logging exception as follows in the work space log file. With the assumption I'm looking at right version of the file [ClassFileReader.java](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.core/blob/R4_7_maintenance/org.eclipse.jdt.core/compiler/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/classfmt/ClassFileReader.java#L712%20ClassFileReader.java), it seems like it has to do something about how some library is compiled. Unfortunately log file does not log any other useful information.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.getMemberTypes(ClassFileReader.java:712)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.cachePartsFrom(BinaryTypeBinding.java:419)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:1022)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:1003)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.accept(Compiler.java:303)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:249)

It's very hard to create a test case. I created another implementation and compiles fine. Copy same block to offending file, compiler error shows up. Trying to dissemble complicated piece of code to which part it's not happy with.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have at least [4.7.1a](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7.1a/#java-9)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, About box of STS shows Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a)

Comment: Have you tried deleting that jar from Maven repo? To force a refresh.

Comment: hard to say what exactly is going wrong here. Maybe generate a small sample project that reproduces the behavior, so that we could take a closer look?